# Update statement with an inner query

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

Below is my script, and it works fine for a single record.

```sql
UPDATE SUPPORT
SET POSTALADDRESSLINE1 =  (SELECT (POSTALDELIVERYNUMBERPREFIX ||' '|| POSTALDELIVERYNUMBERVALUE ||' '|| POSTALDELIVERYSTREETNAME ||' '||  POSTALDELIVERYSTREETTYPE)
FROM SUPPORT WHERE SUPPORTID ='2119022')

WHERE SUPPORTID ='2119022';
```

I now need to do this for about 3000 records. Is there a simple way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't PL/SQL, it's just SQL.  You don't need the subquery in your SET clause. Instead you can just rewrite it like this:

```
UPDATE SUPPORT 
SET POSTALADDRESSLINE1 = POSTALDELIVERYNUMBERPREFIX ||' '|| 
                         POSTALDELIVERYNUMBERVALUE ||' '|| 
                         POSTALDELIVERYSTREETNAME ||' '|| 
                         POSTALDELIVERYSTREETTYPE
WHERE SUPPORTID ='2119022';
```

Once you've tested to make sure that works, adjust your WHERE clause so it selects your 3000 records (or get rid of the WHERE if you're doing the entire table), and you should be all set.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
UPDATE SUPPORT
SET POSTALADDRESSLINE1 = (POSTALDELIVERYNUMBERPREFIX ||' '|| POSTALDELIVERYNUMBERVALUE ||' '|| POSTALDELIVERYSTREETNAME ||' '||  POSTALDELIVERYSTREETTYPE)
WHERE ...;
```